# show two matrices are same $A_1$ and $A_2$ where $A^t=A^{-1}$ and a prop of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

suppose $A_1,A_2  $are $n \times n$ invertible matrix where $A^t=A^{-1}$

and let $e_n= (0,0,...,1)$ where $A_1*e_n=A_2*e_n$

another property is that $\langle A_1*e_n,A_1*e_n \rangle =1$ and $\langle A_2*e_n,A_2*e_n \rangle=1$

Can it be shown that $A_1=A_2$

Comment: Do you mean that both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are orthogonal matrices ($A_i^\top=A_i^{-1}$, $i=1,2$)?

Comment: We dont know that $A_1^{-1}=A_2^{t}$. just checking there is  not some property from linear that I am missing

Comment: no I asked if you assume each one of them orthogonal.

Comment: Yeah $A_{1}^{-1}=A_1^t$ and $A_2^{-1}=A_2^{t}$. Guess I could have worded it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that

$$
\langle A e_n | A e_n \rangle = (A e_n)^t (Ae_n) = e_n^t (A^tA) e_n = e_n^t e_n = 1
$$

that is, the two constraints on the scalar product are redundant, i.e. do not give you more information.

So the only real constraint you have is

$$
A_1 e_n = A_2 e_n
$$

which have infinitely many solutions. To give you an example in $n=3$, imagine

$$
A(\phi) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}\cos \phi & -\sin \phi & 0 \\ \sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right), ~~~\phi\in\mathbb{R}
$$

The set of all matrices $\{A(\phi) \}_\phi$ satisfy $A(\phi)^{t} = A^{-1}(\phi)$, moreover

$$
A(\phi)e_n = e_n
$$

So that, if you call $A_1 = A(\phi)$ and $A_2=A(\theta)$, with $\theta \not=\phi$, you still have $A_1 e_n = A_2 e_n$, but clearly $A_1 \not= A_2$